# regex match nth character from end in string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
molly n=0 results in y
molly n=1 results in l
molly n=3 results in o ... so on
```

I wish to match characters from end like

if second last character in string `molly` is `l` -> true

if fourth last character in string `terminator` is `b` -> false or if `a` -> true

Comment: Share your current regex?

Comment: `.slice()` is a much better tool for this. Regex criteria is specific patterns in a string, the only criteria you need is an index.

Comment: need to pass regex to external lib for ab experiment

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.{n}` to match any `n` characters. If you anchor this to the end of the string, it will match the last `n` characters. Put the character you want to match before this.

```js
console.log(/l.{1}$/.test('molly'));
console.log(/b.{3}$/.test('terminator'));
console.log(/a.{3}$/.test('terminator'));
```